# std::set contains duplicate element after using std::set.erase

Tags: c++, c++11, set

Ehm, I'm in the need of desiging a player timer which will be executed each 30 minuts for each player.

instead of looping all players I made a `std::set<std::pair<playerid,last_time_executed>>` (both are ints `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>`) and:

- I know how to sort as per time value,
- I know how to insert an element without inserting a duplicate playerid(one playerid in set)

But I don't know how to erase an element by playerid only, so I did a few test with random values which my brain chose, and the results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

typedef std::pair<int, int> Pair;
struct Cmp{bool operator ()(const Pair &a, const Pair &b){return a.second < b.second;}};
std::set<Pair, Cmp> myset;

int main() {

    myset.insert(Pair(0, 5));
    myset.insert(Pair(1, 0));
    myset.insert(Pair(1, 1));
    myset.erase(Pair(0, 698));

    std::cout << myset.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto i : myset)
        std::cout << "(" << i.first << "," << i.second << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This actually prints.... (note the duplicated id '1')

3
(1,0)
(1,1)
(0,5)

While this:

```
int main() {

    myset.insert(Pair(0, 5));
    myset.insert(Pair(1, 0));
    myset.insert(Pair(1, 1));

    std::cout << myset.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto i : myset)
        std::cout << "(" << i.first << "," << i.second << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints this (no duplicate id?):

2
(1,1)
(0,5)

andeven more stangely(!) now, this:

```
int main() {

    myset.insert(Pair(0, 5));
    myset.insert(Pair(1, 0));
    myset.insert(Pair(1, 1));
    myset.erase(Pair(0, 0));
    std::cout << myset.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto i : myset)
        std::cout << "(" << i.first << "," << i.second << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

prints this (no duplicate id?):

2
(1,1)
(0,5)

Which is really surprising as I would expect the same output as in the first test.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is what you really want `std::map<playerid, time>`

Comment: then I have to iterate all players anyway and commpare ALL times (std::map implementation doesn't allow sorting by .second value), I want to get the smallest time, then do something on that player, and set his time to the biggest. the requirement is that a playerid may only be once in the whole container, it may not have two times.

Comment: `"then I have to iterat all players anyway and commpare ALL times"` No you don't? `"the requirement is that a playerid may onle be once in the whole container, it may not have two times"` That's exactly what a map is for.

Comment: If players can have more than one time each, then maybe what you need is `std::map<playerid, std::vector<time>>`

Comment: 1) playerid's may not be duplicate in the container, 2) each player may have one time, 3) I need to be able to erase the element by playerid 4) the container needs to be sorted by the time (.second value), a std::map cannot do this :(

Comment: Use a separate vector to keep a list of players sorted by time?

Comment: Either you keep your data sorted by player and loop to get the highest time, or the other way around. You might use something like [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) but I don't think it is worth the effort here.

Comment: Then I would use my original map, and iterate through all players and compare all times in order to find the maximum. That work is going to have to be done one way or the other. You can't find the maximum without checking every value.

Comment: Actually you can do that with 2 maps, one `time` -> `player` and one `player` -> `iterator to the first map`

Comment: Your comparator ignores the ID portion. Why do you expect IDs to be unique, or sorted, or anything?

Comment: @Gizmo You sure about your second part? What you're suggesting is that the first block (3 inserts + 1 erase) produces a 3-element set and the second block (the same 3 inserts) produces a 2-element set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison predicate compares *only* the `second` field of the pair.

The "collision" in the first field is irrelevant.

Change it to get the behaviour you describe:

```
struct Cmp {
    bool operator()(const Pair &a, const Pair &b) { return a.first < b.first; }
};
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7beaf2969f41ff9e)</kbd>**

Also, as others have noticed, this is more like `std::map<idtype, valuetype>`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d7fec22ff6020ac)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<int, int> myset;

int main() {

    mymap.emplace(0, 5);
    mymap.emplace(1, 0);
    mymap.emplace(1, 1);
    mymap.erase(0);

    std::cout << myset.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto i : myset)
        std::cout << "(" << i.first << "," << i.second << ")" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note, to actually update the value for an (existing) key:

```
    mymap[0] = 5;
    mymap[1] = 0;
    mymap[1] = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A `std::set` uses the comparator to ["determine both the order the elements follow in the container and whether two element keys are equivalent"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/).

As your comparator only compares the `last_time_executed` it considers two `Pair` equivalent if they have the same `last_time_executed`. Consequently when you do `myset.erase(Pair(0, 0));` it erases `Pair(1, 0)`.

When I run your second example I get the duplicate player id as I would expect.